# Share Magento Session with CakePHP

Tags: session, cakephp, magento

Basically what I want to do is to share my frontend session of Magento to an application deployed in CakePHP.
The structures are:

public_html/ 
    /appmagento 
    /appcakephp

Anyone nows or has an experience trying this.

Regards,
Luciano

Answer (score 1):

The principal is very easy, just bear in mind that the cookie path is going to need to be the root domain for the session to be accessible.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```